# No space for suggestions in Solr' suggest handler

Tags: solr

I am trying to use "suggest" component in Solr to do auto-completion. I know this is quite a common topic.
I could make it work. I am using solr4.3.1

But, results do not have space between each word.
E.g. giving "appl".looks not bad. But, no space between words, e.g. applemacbook. This should be apple macbook. I am sure that indexed data has space between words.

```
<lst name="spellcheck">
  <lst name="suggestions">
    <lst name="appl">
      <int name="numFound">9</int>
      <int name="startOffset">0</int>
      <int name="endOffset">4</int>
      <arr name="suggestion">
        <str>applea</str>
        <str>applemacbook</str>
        <str>appler</str>
        <str>applewireless</str>
        <str>apple®</str>
        <str>appli</str>
        <str>applianc</str>
        <str>applic</str>
        <str>apply)</str>
      </arr>
    </lst>
  </lst>
</lst>
```

I looked at this http://solr.pl/en/2010/11/15/solr-and-autocomplete-part-2/. I am using the same configuration, "Suggesting phrases". In this example, space is added correctly between words. 
I am not sure if the indexed data is not good.

Schema:

```
<field name="label" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" omitNorms="true"/>

<field name="name_autocomplete" type="textSuggest" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>    
<copyField source="label" dest="name_autocomplete"/>

<fieldType name="textSuggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
 <analyzer>
     <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And,
Query :

```
http://XXXXXXXX/solr/XXXXX/suggest?q=appl&wt=xml&indent=true
```

Comment: What is the definition of the field you're running the suggestions for (in the schema), and how does your query string look?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. And. sorry for late. I attached the schema definition. And, So, a field "label" is the source of data for autocomplete.

Comment: I figured it out.. That was my mistake.. my search component was reffering "label" in stead of "name_autocomplete". That was the reason...